# How can I use a RangeCellAddress to unlock cells using POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm creating a XSSFSheet object from the scratch this object will have a set of cells that belongs to a header and this header must be protected from the end user. All other cells in the spreadsheet must be enable to edit. How can I achieve this? Can I use a RangeCellAddress to do unlock a set of cell?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://www.iprodeveloper.com/print/rpgprogramming/locking-cells-in-hssf-64813) link, it as simple as

> Locking cells in HSSF is easier than you might think. You first have
>   to protect the sheet by calling the protectSheet() method of the
>   HSSFSheet class and assigning a password that will be needed to unlock
>   the sheet from within Excel. Once you've done that, call the
>   setLocked() method for each cell style used in the sheet. For the
>   cells you want to be locked, you have to create separate cell styles
>   from the ones for the cells you want unlocked.

`XSSFSheet` and `XSSFCellStyle` do have methods `protectSheet()` and `setLocked()` respectively, So I am assuming it should work (haven't tried it though).